# How to delete a value from array if exist or push it to array if not exists?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to delete a value from array if exist or push it to array if not exists?

**HTML:**

```
...
<button @click="addToOpenedMenuPosition(item.id)"
...
```

**Vue.js:**

```
data: function() { return {
    openedMenuPositionIds: [],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with eg?

Comment: Yeah can you elaborate more cos we need to know kind if data your array holds are they primitive values or objects... etc and try to give an example like this is my input I want output like this...

Answer (score 32):

A simple implementation using js

```
const arr = ["one","two","three"]; //example array
const newId="one";                 //new id 

if(!arr.includes(newId)){          //checking weather array contain the id
    arr.push(newId);               //adding to array because value doesnt exists
}else{
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(newId), 1);  //deleting
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume the elements are unique so:

Its pretty simple. You can check with `.includes()` if its in the array and find the index of the id with `.indexOf`. Then you `.splice()` the element with the founded index, otherwise just push it into the array.

You need the `return` there to "stop" the function to continue:

```
addToOpenedMenuPosition(id){
   let arr = this.openedMenuPositionIds;
   if(arr.includes(id)){
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(id), 1);
      return;
   }
   arr.push(id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to remove `item.id` from the `openedMenuPositionIds` array which only contains ids as an integer, you can simply use array [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) methods to achieve this like:

```js
var example2 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-2',
  data: function() {
    return {
      openedMenuPositionIds: [],
    }
  },
  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
  
    addToOpenedMenuPosition(id) {

      // Get the index of id in the array
      const index = this.openedMenuPositionIds.indexOf(id);
      if (index > -1) {
        // This means id is present in the array, so remove it
        this.openedMenuPositionIds.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        // This means id is not present in the array, so add it
        this.openedMenuPositionIds.push(id);
      }
      
      // You can use this to debug purpose
      console.log( this.openedMenuPositionIds )
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array by removing the `item.id`, but if `item.id` doesn't exit, then nothing will be removed and we can safely add `item.id`, otherwise we will return the modified array with removed `item.id`.

```
const newMenuPositionIds = menuPositionIds.filter(({id}) => id !== item.id);
if(newMenuPositionIds.length === menuPositionIds.length) {
    newMenuPositionIds.push(item.id);
}
return newMenuPositionIds;
```